# Check for Location permission changes in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using the GeoLocator in my Windows 8 Metro App. Assuming the user has allowed Location access I get their data and save it to cache. When the user reloads the App I do not need to call the GeoLocator as I have it in cache - All good.

However, if the user turns off Location access, how do I detect this and update the cache accordingly so that the App knows to call the GeoLocator again?

I understand that the GeoLocator will fail if the capability is switched off but since I have location data still in the cache I won't be making a call to the GeoLocator to detect this.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to detect Location App Capabilities that I have missed?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Do you really want to cache the location ? What if the user reloads the app' after changing physical location (drove home or whatever...) ?

Comment: I was thinking of the scenario where the App was on a desktop ( like in the olden days:) ) and reading MS documentation it suggested that using the GeoLocator was quite 'expensive' and that lead me to think of cache. However, I am probably getting too concerned about something I don't need to worry about.... thanks again for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but one remark :

- Caching the location is not the best idea. You have no guarantee that when the app is reloaded, the user is in the same geographical location as when the app was suspended. In that case, you should call the GeoLocator every time the app loads/resumes.

Anyhow, if what you're trying to do is check that Location is enabled, you can use the [StatusChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.statuschanged) event in the GeoLocator. Any change in the Location setting while the app is running will trigger the event.

But it's meaningless if the app' is unloaded, the event won't be triggered.

So all in all, if you want to know whether Location was disabled while your app was unloaded, there's no other way than to call [Geolocator.GetGeoPositionAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225537.aspx) every time your app' is loaded and check if it fails or not.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the information - it is useful. I thought there would be a way for me to detect if a user has changed the Apps Location permissions (not their location) without using the GeoLocator at all. I guess that is ultimately what I was after.

Comment: You have no way to know if the location was changed unless you check, and if you check, you might as well just do an update.

Comment: You may have meant this but its the Location "Permission" or capability I wanted to know had changed not the users location..

Answer (score 0):

You can put the GetGeopositionAsync() call in a try - catch. If you get an "Access denied" exception just show a message box that the location permission for the app is disabled.